# Google App Script -The script completed but did not return anything and new row is not inserting

Tags: json, google-apps-script, postman

I am trying to insert a new row in Google Spreadsheet through Google Apps Script.
I am getting same error - "The script completed but did not return anything."
No new row is inserted.

I have tried many youtube tutorials.

My app script file.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m6KuS2Pk4_aL4LcNanWtApE4nFWxwJ4-vokETe-qfao/edit#gid=0");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Items");
   
function doPost(e){
  var action = e.parameter.action;
  if(action == "Id"){
    return addItem(e);
  }   
}
   
function addItem(e){
  var date =  new Date();
  var Id = e.parameter.Id;
  sheet.appendRow([date,Id]);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);   
}
```

No new row is added as a result.
When calling in postman it is showing the same message

"The script completed but did not return anything."

Link for Postman Post is
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzPtXN0xZ8A6M8j9zU3QnJo3T_q0-BWC3sJK0hB7_X_Knp9IM9_/exec

Body in json is
{"action":"Id","Id":"Id1"}

Comment: Put this code in your doPost and log some values out to your sheet for debugging: `function doPost(e){
  var payloadType, isActionID;
  
  var action = e.parameter.action;
  
  payloadType = action === 'string' ? 'payload is string' : 'payload is not string';
  isActionID = action == 'Id' ? 'Passed Test' : 'FAILED!';

  sheet.appendRow([payloadType,isActionID]);
  
  if(action == "Id") {
    return addItem(e);
  }
}`  Is it passing the test to run the next function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function doGet(e){
  var action = e.parameter.action;
  if(action=="Id"){
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//you can open your spreadsheet however you wish but I find this easier if your web app is contained
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Items");
    var date= new Date();
    sh.appendRow([date,action]);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }
}
```